# How to calculate an index value between 1 and 0 for distance, based on a logistic function

Tags: data-transformation, logistic-curve

I work with spatial ecology, and have calculated distances from one island to its neighboring islands.

I want to transform these distances to index values between 0 and 1, where the closest islands are given values close to 1 and the most distant islands get values close to zero.

I also want a logistic curve to dictate which value the distance will be converted to (see image below) [image]

Does anyone know how this can be done mathematically, or with software, such as R or excel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Logistic function is a function that mapping a real number $(-\infty, \infty)$ to $(0,1)$, which is

$$
f(x)=\frac 1 {1+e^{-x}}
$$

In R, function `plogis` looks like this

```
curve(plogis, -5, 5)
```

[image]

Note, your input range is from 10K to 80K which is not a standard logistic function. So we can change the `location` and `scale` parameters in the function. Details see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Logistic.html)

Essentially, `plogis` gives the logistic distribution with location `m` and scale `s` has the distribution function

$$
F(x)=\frac 1 {1+e^{-(x-m)/s}}
$$

If we set the location is 50K and scale is 8K and mirror the curve, we have following function.

```
f<-function(x){
  return(-plogis(x, location=50000, scale=8000)+1)
}

curve(f,10000,80000)
```

[image]

You may further adjust the parameters to satisfy the needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is of much help. 

Is there a way of extracting the y-values, based on the x value from this plot, in R? For example, to find the y-value for 22 554?

Comment: @mhr that is all these function `f` about, try `f(22554)`